# Loop Through HTML Elements and Nodes

Tags: html, xml, parsing, jsoup

I'm working on an HTML page highlighter project but ran into problems when a search term is a name of an HTML tag metadata or a class/ID name; eg if search terms are "media OR class OR content" then my find and replace would do this:

```
<link href="/css/DocHighlighter.css" <span style='background-color:yellow;font-weight:bold;'>media</span>="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div <span style='background-color:yellow;font-weight:bold;'>class</span>="container">
```

I'm using Lucene for highlighting and my current code (sort of):

```
InputStreamReader xmlReader = new INputStreamReader(xmlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
if (searchTerms!=null && searchTerms!="") {
  QueryScorer qryScore = new QueryScorer(qp.parse(searchTerms));
  Highlighter hl = new Highlighter(new SimpleHTMLFormatter(hlStart, hlEnd), qryScore);
}

if (xmlReader!=null) {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(xmlReader);
  String inputLine;
  while((inputLine = br.readLine())!=null) {
    String tmp = inputLine.trim();
    StringReader strReader = new stringReader(tmp);
    HTMLStripCharFilter htm = HTMLStripCharFilter(strReader.markSupported() ? strReader : new BufferedReader(strReader));
    String tHL = hl.getBestFragment(analyzer, "", htm);
    tmp = (tHL==null ? tmp : tHL);
  }
  xmlDoc+=tmp;
}
bufferedReader.close()
```

As you can see (if you understand Lucene highlighting) this does an indiscriminate find/replace. Since my document will be HTML and the search terms are dictated by users there is no way for me to parse on certain elements or tags. Also, since the find/replace basically loops and appends the HTML to a string (the return type of the method) I have to keep all HTML tags and values in place and order. I've tried using Jsoup to loop through the page but handles the HTML tag as one big result. I also tried tag soup to remove the broken HTML caused by the problem but it doesn't work correctly. Does anyone know how to basically loop though the elements and node (data value) of html?

Comment: If I understand your question you want to loop through every element in your html. I think you should reconsider the Jsoup approach. Use the [getAllElements()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getAllElements()) method to get a list of your elements and then use a for each loop to iterate over `Elements`

Comment: This doesn't work, there are too many nested tags (DIVs) and inline tags (P, span, b, ui) and doesn't recurse through the formatting tags.

Comment: @Pigasus Any other alternative would have the same problem you describe in your question. You have no other option but to find all of the text nodes. (eh, i guess you could use regexp, but regexp on html is awful.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the most luck with this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" enconding=\"UTF-8\"?><!DOCTYPE html>");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(txt.getResult());

Element elements = doc.getAllElements(); 
for (Element e : elements) { 
  if (!(e.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("#root"))) {
    sb.append("<" + e.tagName() + e.attributes() + ">" + e.ownText() + "\n"); 
  }// end if
}// end for 
return sb;
```

The one snag I still get is the nesting isn't always "repaired" properly but still semi close. I'm working more on this.